# How to perform spatial queries on polygons in mongodb?

Tags: polygon, mongodb, nosql

I will build a GIS system based on polygons, not just points.
I wanted to use mongodb or postgis.

how do this in mongodb?
[image]

Query A - get the center of a polygon

Query B - distance between two polygons

Query C - list of polygons that are part of a third that I specify

Query D - near distance of the polygon

support SRID?

Comment: Also, take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/best-gis-system-for-high-performance-web-application-postgis-vs-mongodb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently MongoDB does not support these spatial operations - only [Geospatial Indexing of 2d](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) points is supported with some basic accompanying queries (near, within). If you need them you would need to develop support from scratch. Hopefully in the future this will be included.

However if you are interested in storing spatial data in a NoSQL database (instead of a standard relational database, such as PostGIS) you could try [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) with the [geocouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/) extension. Geocouch uses GeoJSON to store geometry so polygons can be stored. However as far as I can see [only boundnig box queries are supported so far](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/359/geocouch-online.pdf) -  which you could use to narrow your search - with hopefully polygon and radius search, and srs support coming soon. (Also, a [tutorial that I found from Todd Jackson](http://boomphisto.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/serving-up-geojson-while-having-rest-on.html) gives a good run-through on getting started. And see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/geojson-geocouch-questions-from-a-newb) on GIS SE.).

Answer (score 2):

I think postgis will be a better bet at this stage.

Query A: use [ST_Centroid](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html)

Query B: use [ST_Distance](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance.html)

Query C: not sure what logic you are applying, but probably something like [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html). Read up on the [9 intersection model](http://postgis.org/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#DE-9IM) if this doesn't do what you were expecting.

Query D: I think you want ST_Distance again. Please explain further if that doesn't do what you were expecting.

Comment: I want to select all polygons that intersect with another polygon as parameter

Comment: my parameter is C and i can get the polygon A and polygon B

Comment: So ST_Intersects should do you what you want. I still recommend reading up on the intersection model.

Comment: see my problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33825/postgis-error-on-select-all-intersetcs-of-a-polygon

Comment: For *D* I'd use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_DWithin.html) in PostGIS